Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000 but kotlin app still run normally
This error: "Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000" in the logcat every time I start the app, but the app still runs normally without crashing.
Other posts about this problem all cause their app to not start at all but mine runs fine for some reason
I am suspecting that the problem could be due to the targeted/compile Sdk version in my build.gradle file and the android device.
Currently I am developing an app on a custom android 10 device while the compileSdk and targetSdk are set to 34(android 14) while the minimumSdk is 29(android 10). If I don't set compileSdk and targetSdk to 34, it keep showing me the error that says google play require minimum Sdk version to be 33+. Now after trying to change those Sdk back to 29, a lot of dependencies need to be changed.
Could this be the reason for the error? If so, can I just ignore it since my app works without a problem, or is there some underlying problem that will cause a crash in the future.

Are you using an emulator ? Is this warning showing also in a real physical device ?

Does this answer your question? "Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000" warning in Logcat on Android Q emulator

@ItzDavi it shows on both physical device and emulator, I remember it started to show this error after I implement mqtt client which required me to install some older dependencies and insert android.enableJetifier=true into my gradle.properties file

Since it's not an ANR or a proper error blocking the execution of the app, I wouldn't bother too much, check if Leviathan comment helps you.
